# Javascript click on a specific link and show div (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript

I have a list or items, and I want to add a class to a div once you click on a certain list item (ie in this example, the last list item).

Code sample below:

```
        <ul class="tier-1"> 
            <li class="first"> 
                 <a href="/">HOME</a> 
            </li> 
            <li>
                 <a href="">SECTIONS</a> 
            </li> 
            <li class="Login Nav Link last"> 
                 <a href="#login" class="Logi Nav **Link**">LOGIN</a> 
            </li> 
        </ul>
        <div class="nav-login"></div>
```

Click on 'LOGIN' link, and the div 'nav-login' should add class 'show'.

**Note: I cannot change the mark-up.**

Comment: Do you have any javascript code you have tried so far?

Comment: -1 as you haven't supplied enough detail for people to give you a rational answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li class="Login Nav Link last"> 
    <a href="#login" class="Login Nav Link" onclick="toggle()">LOGIN</a> 
</li>

<div id="nav-login"></div>

<script>
function toggle(){
    var div1 = document.getElementById('nav-login')
    if (div1.style.display == 'none') {
        div1.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        div1.style.display = 'none'
    }
}
</script>
```

Note that for this method you need to change class="nav-login" into id="nav-login"

Comment: Should probably hook up the toggle function to the link as well?

Comment: I think you've misread my questions.
Problem is theres 2 elements with the same class name 'Link', and I need to target the click on hyperlink with the class 'Link' or target the hyperlink of the last list item. then toggle the div with class name 'nav-login', and I can't change the class to an ID on the div.

Comment: Might be important to mentioned that you need to wait for the DOM to be ready before adding the click method to the anchor.

Comment: There is only one class name 'Link' in your sample.  Just add an onclick to the one link that will call the show/hide method.

Comment: The LI and the child hyperlink within the LI both has the class name Link.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with your markup. You should probably not rely on grabbing the last element, that is just to keep the answer short. You should check the element classname instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
            links[links.length-1].onclick = function () {
                var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
                divs[divs.length-1].className += " show";
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="tier-1">
            <li class="first">
                <a href="/">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">SECTIONS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="Login Nav Link last">
                <a href="#login" class="Login Nav Link">LOGIN</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="nav-login"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to run. In your javascript you should be able to do document.getElementsByTagName("a") to get all of the anchors on the page and bind the click event. Once you've done that, do the same to get the div and add the class.

Comment: @caleb - you have to edit the markup in some way to get the javascript in there. What exactly are the limitations?